# How to configure Mac <Cmd + c> to not exit insert mode for normal mode visual studio vim

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code on my Macbook Pro, I have installed the [basic vim mode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim). When I am in insert mode, and I click `<Cmd + c>` (to copy text in insert mode, I am aware of yank in normal mode), the cursor exits insert mode and enters normal mode. How do I configure visual studio code to not do this?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line to your `settings.json` file (**note**: `<C-c>` for windows, `<D-c>` for Mac since `D` maps to `Cmd`):

```
"vim.handleKeys":{
    "<D-c>": false
},
```